# Dependency Injection not working in SpringBoot with Junit 5 Integration test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

I am working on setting up an Integration test with SpringBoot and Junit5 following this [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-2-with-junit-5-and-mockito-2-for-unit)

But when I run this test file without `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotation gives NullPointerException since RecordService is not being injected.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DefaultTestAnnotations // This is my meta-annotations
public class RecordServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private RecordService recordService; // This is null.

    @Test
    public void whenSearchParametersAreProvided_ItShouldGetTheGoldenRecord() throws MdmMatchServiceException {
        GoldenRecordDTO searchParams = new GoldenRecordDTO();
        searchParams.setCountryCode("CN");
        searchParams.setName("neeraj");
        assertNotNull(recordService.getGoldenRecord(searchParams));
    }
}
```

Is it mandatory to have `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` for running Integration tests?

Comment: Can you also paste imports section of this test class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you imported JUnit4 annotation `org.junit.Test` instead of JUnit5 annotation: `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`.